# Selenium HTMLUnitDriver Cannot Sign in

Tags: selenium, htmlunit

**Update**

I've trying to sign in in this website:

[Salesforce Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/home)

Unfortunately, I have not been successful. Here's my code:

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();

driver.get("https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/home");
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

WebElement btnLogin = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"main-wrapper\"]/header/div[1]/div[2]/span[2]/div/span/button"));
System.out.println(btnLogin);

driver.quit();
```

I'm trying to get the Login button from the header but, I cannot find the Element this is the exception message that I'm getting:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:
>   Unable to locate a node using
>   //*[@id="main-wrapper"]/header/div[1](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/home)/div[2]/span[2]/div/span/button

I'm trying to test the answer from below but, I've not been successful. I would like to understand better how the WebDriverWait works and the until() method.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `(By.xpath("//*[@data-react-class='auth/LoginModalBtn']"))`

Comment: You say you are not successful, what exactly is going wrong? Is an exception thrown, on what line? We need more information to help you.

Comment: @DebanjanB I'm using that to find the Login button on the home page to open the Login options. That part is working well.

Comment: @Frank The problem with my code is, I want to Login to the Trailhead account but, after inserting the email and password and submitting that form, I'd be in the home page of the logged user but, no.

Comment: @lbpeppers So where are you exactly stuck? Or your question got solved?

Comment: @DebanjanB Now is worse than before. I cannot find the login button because the class selector was changed. Is there any tut to understand how to find buttons created dynamically, I'm trying to understand the use of WebDriverWait.

Comment: @lbpeppers Nevermind, update the question with the manual steps which you are trying to automate and exactly where you are stuck, if available the error stack trace for further analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this WebPage the developers were so kind to add special (HTML5) attributes to the HTML for test purposes, called 'data-test'. You can use CSS selectors to locate the Webelements in your Selenium code with help of this attributes. So no complicated Xpath selectors are needed and it's not necessary to iterate through the buttons as @Buaban suggested.

I tested the following C# code and managed to click on the login button.

```
 IWebElement btnLogin = Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("button[data-test=header-login]"));

 btnLogin.Click();
```

I think you are using Java, then it will be:

```
 WebElement btnLogin = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[data-test=header-login]"));

 btnLogin.click();
```

For a more stable solution you have to use Explicit wait:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.css(""button[data-test=header-login]"")));
```

Selenium will try to find the button every 500ms with a maximum of 20 seconds. NoSuchElementExceptions will be ignored till the button is found or till 20 seconds are passed. If the button is not found after 20 seconds a timeout exception will be thrown.

Comment: Thanks for this answer Frank, I'll test this answer and reply back as soon as possible. I'm working on a different project at this moment.

Comment: Thank you, already tested and working perfectly. Frank, do you know why that code works with the Chrome Driver but not with the HTML Unit Driver?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is there are more than one login buttons. Your code wait for the **first button** to be visible. Unfortunately, it won't. So Selenium waits until timeout. 
I recommend creating a method to find the correct button by iterate through all saleforce login buttons and check the property `isDisplayed()`. If it is, use the button. See my example below.

```
private WebElement findLoginButton(WebDriver d, By by) {
    List<WebElement> elements = d.findElements(by);
    for (Iterator<WebElement> e = elements.iterator(); e.hasNext();) {
        WebElement item = e.next();
        if(item.isDisplayed())
                return item;
    }
    return null;
}

@Test
public void testSaleforce() {
    WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
    driver.get("https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/home");
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    WebElement btnLogin = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@data-react-class='auth/LoginModalBtn']"));
    System.out.println(btnLogin);
    btnLogin.click();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
    WebElement btnLoginSalesforce = wait.until((WebDriver d) -> findLoginButton(d,By.cssSelector(".th-modal-btn__salesforce")));
    btnLoginSalesforce.click();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'm testing your solution.